# How may I generate a list of servers with it's associated rack, switch(es), router(s), power supplies and serverroom using the softlayer API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

The idea is that I want to create a dependency graph associated with a server and get a graphical visualization on our redundancy setup in case of unplanned events that might happen in softlayer datacenter(s).

So I would like to know how to pull out associated information (rack, switch(es), router(s), power supplies, and server room) for servers and have an updated "weather map" towards internal monitoring systems and unplanned events from softlayer's side.

Answer (score 0):

Try using objects mask to get the vlan of the VSI and the Router, switch, etc acsssoiciated to the the VLAN

take alook at this request for VSI:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getVirtualGuests?resultLimit=0,2&objectMask=mask[serverRoom,networkVlans[primaryRouter[downstreamNetworkHardware[downstreamNetworkHardware]],secondaryRouter]]]
```

for BareMetal serer the request is similar:

```
GET https://api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Account/getHardware?resultLimit=0,2&objectMask=mask[serverRoom,networkVlans[primaryRouter[downstreamNetworkHardware[downstreamNetworkHardware]],secondaryRouter]]]
```

but keep in mind that this request contains a big amount of data and it may fail, to avoid the fail you can use resutlLimits

regards

Comment: Do you by any chance have an updated objectMask on how to also include servers in this following example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34914945/can-you-pull-network-status-information-from-the-softlayer-api  ?

Comment: Nope, the example in the python example is calling the Account::getObject method to list the bare metal servers with their routers, using that method, you can use this mask:  objectMask=mask[hardware[serverRoom,networkVlans[primaryRouter]]], The big issue with what you want to do is that the object mask performs a heavy query in the dabase and when you accounts have several data the request will fail, you need to break down your request in small requests.